# how to upload a all type of documents to google docs using android?

Tags: android, google-docs

I am new of android development, I have not any idea for upload document in google docs,mean while i searched in google but i have not any sample code for upload document into google docs using android. i dont know which google api is using, So please give some ideas and any tutorials(links) for this.

Thanks advance.
senthil.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a place to start https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/